I Have a rank-order list of healthcare priorities which i assessed using a survey between doctors in two different countries
I used a survey to assess the rank order of certain healthcare priorities between healthcare providers in two different countries. I have tested the man rank-values attributed to each priority using the standard independent sample t-test but I am trying to see if order of priorities is different.
Is simply showing the order (from 1 to 6) is different enough or is there a test i can use to show that the order is different.

Please do not take this personnaly, but this kind of question brings to mind the following quote from R. Fisher

To consult the statistician after an experiment is finished is often merely to ask him to conduct a post mortem examination. He can perhaps say what the experiment died of. -- Ronald Fisher (1938)

This being said, the next comment is about the scale of your measurement. You used ranks, which is ordinal data (the order is meaningful, but the distances between the levels is not constant, between levels, or accross subjects). You may want to read Stevens's seminal paper on this. So computing means, standard deviations, and running t-tests (or other such tests) are not "permissible" (Stevens's terminology) statistics. Since your scale is ordinal, you are limited to ordinal tests, and in your case, more specifically rank-order tests (which is perfect, as your data are ranks).
One option is to run 6 (1 for each priority) Mann-Whitney U tests (MWUt), to compare between the 2 countries. As you will be running 6 tests, you should use a multiple comparison correction (MCC) (Sidak?). This will tell you for which priority the 2 countries significantly differ, and for which the differences may still be due to "chance".
You could also use Mood's median test, to compare the median ranks accross countries (still would need MCC). That test also is valid for ordinal scale data. MWUt should have more power though.
Now, in your case, if I know the priorities assigned by your subjects for the first 5 items, I can fully determine the 6th (it is whichever they did not yet pick). So your 6 samples are not independent; that may have an impact on the comparisons, but I honestly am not sure how significant it could be, or how to deal with it.
